# Optimize if-statement (a > 0 && b > 0 && a + b == c) in C#

Tags: c#, optimization, if-statement

I'm currently doing some graph calculations that involves adjacency matrices, and I'm in the process of optimizing every little bit of it.

One of the instructions that I think can be optimized is the one in the title, in it's original form:

```
if ((adjMatrix[i][k] > 0) && (adjMatrix[k][j] > 0) && (adjMatrix[i][k] + adjMatrix[k][j] == w))
```

But for ease I'll stick to the form provided in the title:

```
if (a > 0 && b > 0 && a + b == c)
```

What I don't like is the > 0 part (being an adjacency matrix, in it's initial form it contains only 0 and 1, but as the program progresses, zeros are replaced with numbers from 2 onwards, until there are no more zeros.

I've done a test and removed the > 0 part for both a and b, and there was a significant improvement. Over 60088 iterations there was a **decrease of 792ms**, from 3672ms to 2880ms, which is 78% of the original time, which to me is excellent.

So my question is: can you think of some way of optimizing a statement like this and having the same result, in C#? Maybe some bitwise operations or something similar, I'm not quite familiar with them.

Answer with every idea that crosses your mind, even if it's not suitable. I'll do the speed testing myself and let you know of the results.

**EDIT:** This is for a compiler that I'm gonna run it myself on my computer. What I just described it's not a problem / bottleneck that I'm complaining of. The program in it's current form runs fine for my needs, but I just want to push it forward and make it as basic and optimized as possible. Hope this clarifies a little bit.

**EDIT** I believe providing the full code it's a useful thing, so here it is, but keep in mind what I said in the bold below. **I want to concentrate strictly on the if statement**. The program essentially takes an adjacency matrix and stores all the route combinations that exists. Then there are sorted and trimmed according to some coefficients, but this I didn't included.

```
int w, i, j, li, k;
int[][] adjMatrix = Data.AdjacencyMatrix;
List<List<List<int[]>>> output = new List<List<List<int[]>>>(c);

for (w = 2; w <= 5; w++)
{
    int[] plan;

    for (i = 0; i < c; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            if (j == i) continue;
            if (adjMatrix[i][j] == 0)
            {
                for (k = 0; k < c; k++) // 11.7%
                {
                    if (
                        adjMatrix[i][k] > 0 && 
                        adjMatrix[k][j] > 0 && 
                        adjMatrix[i][k] + adjMatrix[k][j] == w) // 26.4%
                    {
                        adjMatrix[i][j] = w;

                        foreach (int[] first in output[i][k])
                            foreach (int[] second in output[k][j]) // 33.9%
                            {
                                plan = new int[w - 1];
                                li = 0;

                                foreach (int l in first) plan[li++] = l;
                                plan[li++] = k;
                                foreach (int l in second) plan[li++] = l;

                                output[i][j].Add(plan);
                            }
                    }
                }

                // Here the sorting and trimming occurs, but for the sake of
                // discussion, this is only a simple IEnumerable<T>.Take()
                if (adjMatrix[i][j] == w)
                    output[i][j] = output[i][j].Take(10).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Added comments with profiler results in optimized build**.

By the way, the timing results were obtained with exactly this piece of code (without the sorting and trimming which dramatically increases execution time). There weren't another parts that were included in my measurement. There is a Stopwatch.StartNew() exactly before this code, and a Console.WriteLine(EllapsedMilliseconds) just after.

If you want to make an idea about the size, the adjacency matrix has 406 rows / columns. So basically there are only for-instructions combined which execute many many iterations, so I haven't got many options of optimizing. Speed is not currently a problem, but I want to make sure I'm ready when it'll become.

**And to rule out the 'optimize another parts' problem, there is room for talk in this subject also, but for this specific matter, I just want to find solution for this as an abstract problem / concept. It may help me and others understand how the C# compiler works and treats if-statements and comparisons, that's my goal here.**

Comment: Are you really sure this is the main point at which you are suffering speed problems (we can't tell form what you've posted).

The best way to optimise is to profile, identify the bottlenecks, and then improve those.  I'd be surprised if your biggest slowdown was that if statement.

Comment: @Goz I edited the question to make it a little clearer. The program runs fine, but I want to make it run faster.

Comment: Can a or b be negative? != may be marginally faster than >. However, a: id doubt that is the bottleneck, and b: id be considering unsafe array access

Comment: Why do you care about 3/4 of a second difference?

Comment: @Tiby:  It still doesn't quite answer my point.  You want to make it run faster ... it is 99% probable (Don't forgt 98% of statistics are made up on the spot ;)) that you an get HUGE speedups elsewhere rather than by optimising an if statement.

Comment: @Goz I know what you're talking about, but the whole piece of code that does the hard work has only 40-50 lines. The other 2 locations I can optimize it is an array concatenator, and a list selector, and I'm gonna optimize them also. The only alternative is to find another way to achieve the same result, but I don't think it's the case right now.

Comment: @Ramhound 1. for debugging purposes: if the programs run faster, I don't have to wait every time for it to do it's job. 2. because maybe at some point in time, it's going to take it 10 times the time, and that 500 ms are going to become 5 seconds, and I care about that

Comment: @MarcGravell a or b are positive ( 0 or more ). Checking with != is also ok

Comment: Tiby, can you show declaration of `adjMatrix` and `w`?

Comment: adjMatrix is int[][] and it has around 450 rows and 450 columns, and w is int

Comment: What are the maximum values in the matrix? (ie. could one do some bit-slicing or other distributed arithmetic or exploit parallelism?)

Comment: Tiby, please check my answer, I added a suggestion about `int[][]`.

Comment: One lesson here is always optimize high level first: As the matrix seems to be overwritten, isn't there either an error, or isn't it enough to scan only upper right triangle of the matrix?

Comment: It isn't enough with the upper right triangle because this is a directed graph.

Comment: @Tiby: ok. But if you have made element [k][i]=w, doesn't that make it impossible to make later [j][k]=w too?

Comment: The only modification is adjMatrix[i][j] = w. And since w is always non-zero, after it's modified, adjMatrix[i][j] == 0 prevents it from entering the loop

Comment: Why do you assume you need exactly these for loops? Have you considered a different algorithm? This should be your first step, as a quicksort in perl is faster than a bubble sort in hand-optimized assembler :-)

Answer (score 6):

You can replace `a>0 && b>0` with `(a-1)|(b-1) >= 0` for signed variables *a* and *b*.

Likewise, the condition `x == w` can be expressed as `(x - w)|(w - x) >= 0`, since when `x != w` either left or the right part of the expression will toggle the sign bit, which is preserved by bit-wise *or*. Everything put together would be `(a-1)|(b-1)|(a+b-w)|(w-a-b) >= 0` expressed as a single comparison.

Alternatively a slight speed advantage may come from putting 
the probabilities in increasing order:

Which is more likely `(a|b)>=0` or `(a+b)==w` ?

Comment: I believe it is. (a|b)<0 is equal to (a<0 or b<0 or (a<0 and b<0))

Comment: Reordering is a good idea, but here it might be offset with the difference between the cost of doing the addition vs. that of the simpler zero-check.

Comment: what happens if a=0 and b=1? (a|b) > 0 => True, but (a > 0 && b > 0) => False

Comment: David: either that is increasing order, or I had one too many drinks.

Comment: (a|b)>0 was faster, with 2954ms, but as you guys here mentioned, doesn't work correctly. I'm gonna try now with the edit made by Michael

Comment: It's not correct. If `a = 0` and `b = 1` then `a > 0 && b > 0` is `false`, but `a | b == 1` and `1 > 0` is `true`.

Comment: The more I think of it, the more it seems like just asking `a!=0 && b!=0` would be the simplest, fastest way to do this. Zero-checks are supposed to be super fast (certainly faster than larger-than-zero checks). Since your adjacency matrix is non-negative, asking for !=0 is equivalent to asking for >0.

Comment: @Avish - That doesn't do the same thing though. What if a == -1?

Comment: @BlueVoodoo: I assume there are no negatives in an adjacency matrix. Of course this won't work for the general case.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how well C# optimizes things like this, but it's not so difficult to try to store  `adjMatrix[i][k]` and `adjMatrix[k][j]` in temporary variables not to read memory twice. See if that changes things in any way.

It's hard to believe that arithmetic and comparison operations are the bottleneck here. Most likely it's memory access or branching. Ideally memory should be accessed in a linear fashion. Can you do something to make it more linear?

It would be good to see more code to suggest something more concrete.

**Update:** You could try to use two-dimensional array (`int[,]`) instead of a jagged one (`int[][]`). This might improve memory locality and element access speed.

Comment: Arithmetic comparison typically implies branching, so it's a good starting point. (notice that OP already did some profiling)

Comment: In this case one can indeed cache one of those values early and skip at least one for loop. Also by making the array 1-dimensional, one could also avoid one possibly costly address calculation: adjMatrix[K][j] == (adjmatrix+j) + K * constant;

Comment: Multidimensional arrays are almost equivalent as timing, maybe slightly slower (100ms)

Answer (score 3):

The order of the logical tests could be important (as noted in other answers). Since you are using the short circuit logical test (&& instead of &), then the conditions are evaluated from left to right, and the first one it finds that is false, will cause the program to stop evaluating the conditional and continue executing (without executing the `if` block). So if there is one condition is the far more likely to be `false` than the rest, that one should go first, and the next should be the next most likely one to be `false`, etc.

Another good optimization (which I suspect is really what gave you your performance increase --rather than simply dropping out some of the conditions) is to assign the values you are pulling from the arrays to local variables.

You are using `adjMatrix[i][k]` twice (as well as `adjMatrix[k][j]`) which is forcing the computer to dig through the array to get the value. Instead, before the if statement, set each of those to a local variable each time, then do your logic test against those variables.

Comment: If I switch the order of the conditions (put the sum in front) there is actually an increase of 100ms. I thought about assigning the arrays to a variable, but didn't test it, but I'm gonna do this right now.

Comment: Assigning the array values to variables executes in 3900ms, so worse. I believe it's an extra overhead of assigning values than reading from an array.

Comment: I'm guessing this is happening in some sort of loop, does it help if the variables are declared outside all of the loops (negating the need to allocate and de-allocate memory), and simply assigning the value to the variable before the `if` statement?

Comment: Tiby, are you running an optimized build? Because it should not really happen on the optimized code, the temporaries should go into the registers.

Comment: Forgot to check that. It wasn't optimized. I've done it, and the execution time decreased by 500ms. Also, after I profiled it, the if remained at 26% work, but part of the other 20-30% load was switched from plan = new int[w-1] to the in in second foreach. But this was obtained with my initial code, not with the variable-array-storing one

Answer (score 1):

I agree with others who say it's unlikely that this simple statement is your bottleneck and suggest profiling before you decide on optimizing this specific line. But, as a theoretical experiment, you can do a couple of things:

1. Zero-checks: checking for `a != 0 && b != 0` will probably be somewhat faster than `a >= 0 && b >= 0`. Since your adjacency matrix is non-negative, you can safely do this.
2. Reordering: if testing just `a + b == c` is faster, try using this test first and only then test for `a` and `b` individually. I doubt this will be faster because addition and equality check is more expensive than zero checks, but it might work for your particular case.
3. Avoid double indexing: look at the resulting IL with ILDASM or an equivalent to ensure that the array indexes are only dereferenced once, not twice. If they aren't, try putting them in local variables before the check.

Comment: Zero checks of integers are rarely faster than additions or comparisons, because CPU clock speeds are typically determined by the addition units propagation time.

Comment: Even under that normalization, I still think it's faster because a zero-check requires less instructions than addition followed by an equality-check. But then again, things probably changed a lot since I last dealt with machine code optimizations.

Comment: In IA: mov eax,[ebx]; cmp eax,0  vs test eax,eax vs add eax,0 vs or eax,eax; vs dec eax,1 followed by jns, jne, je, jc. Where is the difference? (loads do not affect flags in most architectures)

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen, I think we've been debating over two different claims :) I got confused and tried to claim that zero-checking each variable independently is cheaper than checking their sum against a third variable, which might be true but is irrelevant since you were debating the point of whether zero-checks are cheaper than greater-than-zero checks, which I accept might not be true.

Comment: apparently. There are still a couple of open questions: is a!=0 && b!=0 really faster than a*b>0, does the order of comparisons matter and does the amount of branching matter. The fewest amount of branches would be taken with a combined statement: a*b*(a+b!=w)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're calling a function you don't optimize conditionals. Its pointless. However if you really want to theres a few easy things to keep in mind

Conditions are checked if something is a zero (or not), if the highest bit is set (or not) and a compare (== or !=) is essentially a - b and checking if its zero (==0) or not (!=0). So a is unsigned then a>0 is the same as a!=0. If a is signed then a<0 is pretty good (this uses the check on highest bit) and is better then a<=0. But anyways just knowing those rules may help.

Also fire up a profiler, you'll see conditionals take 001% of the time. If anything you should ask how to write something that doesnt require conditionals.

Comment: In my case this conditional took up 23.8% from the execution time. So why talk about general cases? Also I insisted you read my last paragraph, I mainly wanted to understand how things work, not just solve my problem, which is not a problem at all. I'll check what you explained about how conditions are checked. Thanks

Comment: @Tiby: That isnt the code your testing is it? because i only see two conditions. The ==0 and ==w. Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Status_register, generally Z (zero), N (negative or sign) + V and C flags are used in most/all cpus. V (overflow) is essential C (carry) but used with two sign numbers. When you do unsigned 0 - unsigned 1 it cause the value to wrap around  which sets the C flag. V is same idea but both sides have to be negative or non negative number. Anyways thats the most important part. You should check if functions take a lot of time

Comment: and ask if it is possible to rewrite something to use no conditionals

Comment: The == 0 is outside the if that is outside the for loop. And the == w is last after the two > 0 's. They're vertically aligned to be more visible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered reversing the logic?

```
if (a > 0 && b > 0 && a + b == c)
```

could be rewritten to:

```
if (a == 0 || b == 0 || a + b != c) continue;
```

Since you don't want to do anything in the loop if any of the statements are false, then try to abort as soon as possible (if the runtime is that smart, which I assume).

The operation which is the heaviest should be last, because if first statement is true, the others doesn't need to be checked. I assumed that the addition is the heaviest part, but profiling it might tell a different story.

However, I haven't profiled these scenarios my self, and with such trivial conditionals, it might even be a drawback. Would be interesting to see your findings.

Comment: The results were the same. Probably the compiler logic is the same.

Comment: Inverting a conditional in this way only changes the layout of the code (which could be great for readability), but usually results in the same compiled code. In fact I'd be surprised if the compiler doesn't do this kind of 'optimizations' itself.

Comment: But it would only be applicable for trivial conditionals like this one. If I have multiple method invocations that return a boolean, then I expect all of them to be run if I use AND, if the compiler would reverse the logic, that would no longer be the case. It's clever of the compiler to actually be able to make that assumption.